# when to use Pig and when to use java for Mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop

As per my knowledge,we can use pig for Mapreduce.And also java can be used for it.Can you please explain me in what scenarios which one to be used?

Comment: I guess this can be a long answer or analysis, so I leave it to someone with more time... you might want to include hive and scalding in the comparison as well. It's more like a balance between simplicity and amount of time you need to write it vs control and testability of the job. IMO in order of simple to controlable/testable it goes hive -- pig -- scalding -- java.

Answer (score 3):

If you *can* do it in Pig (or Hive), do it in Pig (or Hive).

Otherwise, do it in Java MapReduce.

---

Benefits of Pig:

- Structured data like CSV is REALLY easy to load and use
- Not that much slower than Java
- Not prone to Java-level bugs
- Easier to read and write
- No need to compile: easier to maintain, easier to deploy

---

There are a few things you may think you can't do in Pig at first and want to use Java for, but you can do it in Pig once you know more about it:

- [You can write user-defined loaders in Java](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#load-store-functions). You are going to write some Java to parse out that complicated data format anyways, so why not do it in a Pig Loader?
- Nesting [`map` and `bag` datatypes](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#data-types) can model hierarchical data structures pretty well, but you'll probably have to write a ton of UDFs.
- You can [use Java MapReduce in Pig](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#mapreduce). This allows you to do the hard operation in Pig, but the easier stuff elsewhere.

There are a few here, but you get the point. Pig is very customizable, and you'll end up writing less Java in general.

---

Basic stuff is easy. We can do things like hierarchical data structures, and custom loading with a bit of effort. Ok, so what's left?

- Exotic uses of partitioners to do something MapReduce isn't intended for.
- Really nasty data formats or completely unstructured data (video, audio, raw human-readable text)
- Doing complex operations in the DistributedCache (basic things can be done with [`JOIN` and `USING 'replicated'`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#join-inner))

Hopefully others can add things they couldn't do in Pig in the comments.